# Are there recursive complete proof systems incorporating the omega-rule?

Tags: logic

By the omega-rule, I mean the infinitary rule which licenses one to infer (x)F(x) from F(0),F(1),...  Are there proof systems incorporating this rule which are recursive?  If so, why favor proof systems with only finitary rules?  Finally, are there proof systems for (second-order) PA which incorporate this rule, are recursive, and are complete?

Answer (score 1):

No - given any Turing machine $\Phi$, I can (effectively, even!) come up with a formula $p(x)$ in the language of $PA$ such that $\forall xp(x)$ is true iff $\Phi(p)$ does *not* halt and equal $1$, ever. Specifically, using the Diagonal Lemma let $p(x)$ code the statement "$\Phi(\ulcorner p\urcorner)$ does not halt and equal $1$ in at most $x$ many steps."

As for incorporating this rule into "first-order PA", note that the rule is inherently *non* first order, since e.g. it prevents Compactness.

Comment: Of course this doesn't mean the omega-rule is *uninteresting*, just that it forces you into non-recursive territory. Indeed there are plenty of times that infinitary (non-recursive) rules are useful for analyzing recursive (hence finitary) systems, e.g. using the omega-rule to simplify Gentzen's original analysis of Con(PA). But that's a different question.

Comment: Thank you, all!  But this paper -- http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bsl/1102022662 -- by Torkel Franzen seems to reference a proof by Shoenfield of a completeness theorem for a recursive omega rule.  Can someone explain in non-specialist terms what this is saying, and how it relates to the above?  Thanks again.

Comment: (Thanks, Noah, for the clarification about first-order.  I edited my post accordingly.)

Answer (score 1):

There is a fundamental challenge with trying to make a recursive proof system that uses infinitary rules.

Usually, a recursive proof system is a system in which there is a collection of *formal deductions*, coded by natural numbers, so that a Turing machine can recognize and manipulate the deductions via their codes.

If we move to a system with infinitary rules, formal deductions can now be infinite, so it is more challenging to represent them as finite objects.  More importantly, it will not be possible, in general, for a Turing machine to verify that a rule with an infinite number of hypotheses was applied correctly. So the set of correct deductions will not be decidable.

The $\omega$-rule certainly does have some strength, but the problems with infinitary rules and recursive proof systems are more fundamental than that. This is why, for the purposes of recursive proof systems, it is necessary to stick to finitary rules of inference. Of course, it is common to look at infinitary rules anyway, although they won't correspond to recursive proof systems. There is no reason to limit ourselves to *only* recursive proof systems.